# Percentage sign in `print` and `message`

Tags: message, print, format

I am trying to output

```
Humidity: 42%
```

using both functions `print` and `message`. While `print` has no problem with the literal percentage sign, `message` throws a "Format string ends in middle of format specifier".
What am I missing?

```
(defun demo()
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (setq text (format "Humidity: %s%%" 42))
    (print text)
    (message text)
    ))
(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'demo)
```

Comment: `C-h f message`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 4):

By running `(message (format ...))`, you're using the string as a format **twice**.

`print` takes an *object* as its parameter, while `message` takes a *format string*. Use `"%s"` as the format and you can specify the string as the second optional argument to `message`:

```
(setq text (format "Humidity %s%%" 42))
(print text)
(message "%s" text)
  ⇒ "Humidity 42%"
```

or don't run format on `text` before sending it to `message`:

```
(setq value 42)
(setq format "Humidity %s%%")
(print (format format value))
(message format value)
  ⇒ "Humidity 42%"
```

Comment: @NickD: The `print` line was missing in one of them.